# Dynamic subdomains on Mac os x

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, mac, wildcard-subdomain

Here is my ideal setup that I would like to figure out how to do:

I have a domain professionally hosted:

Example.net

I have a subdomain, home.example.net that points to my Mac mini at home. I've already got this working just fine. The document root for home.example.net is /Users/me/Sites

I want to setup dynamic subdomains such that anything that comes before home.example.net (the regex version: *.home.example.net) has the document root: /Users/me/Sites/$1

For example: visiting bacon.home.example.net will have the doc root /Users/me/Sites/bacon

How can I get this setup so I don't have to add a new vhost for every project?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable `mod_rewrite`

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

and add a the following directives to your Apache configuration:

```
ServerAlias *.home.example.net

<Directory /User/me/Sites>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^home\.example\.net
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).home\.example\.net
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://home.example.net/%1/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

Of course you need to make sure that the DNS records and subdirectories for each subdomain exist.

Comment: Is there anyway to bypass "making sure the DNs record exists"? How does one do that?

Comment: Not unless you want to start managing `hosts` files. How is the browser supposed to resolve `foo.home.example.net` to an IP address without name resolution?

Comment: If he's already mapping `*.home.example.net` to his localhost, that shouldn't matter

Comment: You're right. I hadn't thought of wildcard DNS records.

Comment: So just the mod rewrite will work then?!

Comment: If `host SOMETHING.home.example.net` returns an address it should work, yes.